# D3: Color a "Element" on a graph by the value of the key

Tags: d3.js

I have no code to show - I do not know where to start. That is my problem. Normally I mess around for long, which I have done. However - I am a noob in coding so its hard for me (somewhat).

I know how D3 works, the basics. I can create a few simple colorScales with categories or ranges. What I want to do is the following.

Each dot or bar or line on my chart will be a certain color dependent on the "Value" of the "Key" in my JSON file.

e.g. "Supplier_name" : "FLYBE BRITISH EUROPEAN" 
Will equate to Purple
e.g. "Supplier_name": "EASYJET"
Will equate to Orange

And so on and so on.

Do I create a new JSON array with an object inside that lists each Supplier's name with an associated color I add as it's value? Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/11313583)

I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO :(!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a property with the desired color value to your data, in your case your JSON file, and then apply the color to your elements. Just like you would apply any other attributes.

Here is an example.

```js
var margin        = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}, 
    w             = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h             = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    circleRadii   = 15,
    // add colors to your data
    circleData    = [{x: 10, y: 10, c: "yellow"}, {x: 50, y: 80, c: "green"}, {x: 90, y: 10, c: "red"}];

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", h + margin.left + margin.right)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(circleData)
.enter()
.append("circle");

var circleAttr = circles
.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
.attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
.attr("r", circleRadii)
// apply your color from the dataset
.style("fill", function (d) { return d.c; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That helps a lot to understand it better bro! Thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Happy coding.

Comment: I pulled my data from an external resource - like 1000 records (objects) in an array. Each object has a Supplier_Name with a value of the Supplier. Is there a way I can add the color (key) with its value = "to the color I want" to each object? like - above examples would be in 2 separate records (objects).